# Attempting to prevent SQL injection when referencing an Oracle Package dynamically with JPA

Tags: oracle, jpa

I've gone down a bit of a path and hit a wall with how this could be possibly achieved.

Basically, a query is constructed using JPA and passed to an Oracle DB.  On the DB there is a Package, used to generate a reference, and this is dynamically named, based on the environment.  This value is user-editable, and stored as a DB property within the application.  I don't have any control over the architecture of this.

At a pre-JPA stage, a Query String is generated using the reference value for the Package, which is set as a property (again, I can't change the way this has been designed).  I set this up using the `Query` method `setParameter()`, like so:

*(pseudocode replacing the irrelevant parts for focused context)*

```
String referenceRef = [ reference is fetched from DB properties ];

String queryString = "SELECT ?1 FROM sys.dual";
final Query myQuery = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery( queryString );
myQuery.setParameter( 1, referenceRef );

return myQuery.getSingleResult();
```

I pretty much did this as a reflex, only to realise (in retrospec, quite obviously) that this won't actually work, as it is escaping the element that should not be escaped...

So, where the `referenceRef = "DynamicallyNamedPackage.DoThisDynamicallyNamedThing"`, the above code will just return `"DynamicallyNamedPackage.DoThisDynamicallyNamedThing"`, as it is obviously making it safe, and the point of doing so is, to a certain extent, the antethesis of what I'm trying to do.

Is it possible to achieve this without creating a whole chunk of additional code?  All I can currently think of, as an alternative, is to query `dba_procedures` for all package objects that match, and using the result of that query to construct the `queryString` (hence circumnavigating using any user-editable values), but it feels like it's going to be convoluted.  This is the alternative, which I am using in lieu of an improvement:

```
final String verifyReference = "SELECT object_name FROM "
            + "dba_procedures WHERE object_type = 'PACKAGE' AND object_name =?1";
final Query refQuery = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery( verifyReference );

refQuery.setParameter( 1, referenceRef );
final String result = refQuery.getSingleResult();

final String queryString = "SELECT " + result + " FROM sys.dual";
final Query myQuery = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery( queryString );

return myQuery.getSingleResult();
```

It will essentially look up the user-editable property reference against a list of existing packages, then use the result of that query for building the original reference.  It has more null checking and so on involved, and does remove the vulnerability, but feels a bit 'unpolished'.

*(As has already been mentioned in the comments, this sort of is designed to need a SQL injection, but needs to prevent "SQL Injection" as a definition of not allowing the DB to be manipulated outside of the design by using an unintended value.)*

Comment: You don't want to prevent SQL injection here. You want to do SQL injection, don't you? If this design has been chosen, I guess it was considered OK for a user to choose and store the name of thing to select from dual, and that the user or the value has been validated already. So... so be it.

Comment: I guess the answer is 'yes', based on the concept of SQL Injection being taken literally, but not so much in the concept of "SQL Injection" being unauthorised/unintended hijacking of a query that allows SQL (rather than a referenced object) to be injected.  The design is something of an issue, but not one that I have control over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle dictionary view [`all_procedures`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-3DED0AD5-4220-4C77-AE16-07060A19E6DF.htm#REFRN20168) contains a list of all procedures accessible to the current user.

Specifically in the view there are columns `OWNER, OBJECT_NAME (=package name), PROCEDURE_NAME`.

You may use this view to sanitize the configured input by simple adding an `EXISTS` subquery such as:

```
select 
 ?
from dual where exists (
  select null from all_procedures
  where 
   OWNER||'.'||OBJECT_NAME||'.'||PROCEDURE_NAME = upper(?) and
  object_type = 'PACKAGE');
```

You will have to bind twice the same input parameter.

The query returns `no data` if there is not procedure with the given name, so you may raise an exception.

The query above expects a full qualified stored procedure name, i.e. `owner.package.procedure`,  you'll have to adapt it slightly if you allow unqualified names (without the `owner`).

Comment: Thanks - is there a benefit to the nested `EXISTS` statement over a single `SELECT PROCEDURE_NAME WHERE PRODECURE_NAME = ?`, aside from stylistic?

Comment: @ChrisJ the point is, the view `all_procedures` can contain several rows for a procedure (one for each overload). Using `EXISTS` returns maximal one row. The same can be achieved using `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: Ah okay - I was probably being too terse in my description, but this will probably be extended for targetting a specific function within the package, at which point there should only be a single row return?

Comment: In general case, a packaged procedure may have several *overloads* (i.e. same procedure name, but different parameters), therefor you may get more rows for a single `OWNER.PACKAGE_NAME.PROCEDURE_NAME`.

Comment: That makes sense - I have used an amended version, but the query was very useful; thanks!